# Java url parsing

Tags: java, parsing, url

Okay so I'm trying to parse the url and extract partial data.. However it doesn't seem to be extracting the exact data I want.. I assume it's extracting ID and not Value.

This is the code I'm using

```
            price = readUrl(apiUrl + String.valueOf(id)).split(",")[1].split(":")[1];
            String price2 = price.substring(0, price.length() - 1);
            return Integer.parseInt(price2);
```

the url I'm using is

```
https://api.rsbuddy.com/grandExchange?a=guidePrice&i=
```

parameter i = id of item, for this example we will use " 2619 "

which returns,

```
{"overall":49907,"buying":0,"buyingQuantity":0,"selling":49907,"sellingQuantity":2}
```

the information I want is

```
49907
```

from

```
{"overall":49907,
```

Comment: "Parsing the result to a Json Object using a json library and getting any field you like" seems like a better idea

Comment: This is not about URLs. It is about parsing JSON strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSONObject`:

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(YOUR_STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_PARSE);
  Integer price = jsonObject.getInt("overall");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get from API is a JSON. So you can simply use JSONObject.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

You can do something like:

```
    jsonObject.getInt("overall");
```